# FunctionPointer uniqueness for anonymous function

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-function

Can I be sure that `.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer()` is unique for each anonymous function?
Want to do

```
public static T Get<T>(Func<T> getDataCallback) where T : class
{
    string cacheID = getDataCallback.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().ToString();
    var data = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheID) as T;
    if (data == null)
    {
        data = getDataCallback();
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheID, data);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you want to know.

Comment: You also might say which API this is. Clearly, working code wouldn't start with ".".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean anonymous delegates. Different delegates have different `d.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctonPointer()` results, but first we need to define "different delegates". If two delegates refers to the same method, they are considered the same, like:

```
Action a = new Action(MyMethod);
Action b = new Action(MyMethod);   
//a == b, that is, Delegate.Equals(a,b) is true
```

Anonymous delegates are always different, even they look the same:

```
Action a = delegate { MyMethod(); }; 
Action b = delegate { MyMethod(); };
```

So **the answer to your first question is YES**, but **your cache possibly won't work as expected**! If your application pool is recycled, the FunctionPointer value will change even your `getDataCallback` delegate remains the same. Be aware of this.

Comment: Can you give some more information when my cache possibly won't work?

Comment: @Evgraf: Write a simple console application, and run it twice, you will get different function pointer values for a same delegate. This is the same scenario as the application pool is recycled.